# Sharing an event from a Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-events

I have an event on my Facebook Page that I would like to share on my own personal news feed. There is no share button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you are logged in/using Facebook as the Page you may not be able to share it (I have found this to be inconsistent), but you should be able to share the event to your personal feed when using Facebook as yourself by going into the “events” section of your page and then clicking “share”.

[image: facebook event]